# Can a subordinate conjunction join a participial phrase to an independent clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

In the sentence, "They were thrilled after hearing about the new store," is the word "after" a subordinating conjunction joining the participial phrase "hearing about the new store" to the independent clause "They were thrilled. I thought the rule was that subordinating conjunctions join clauses.

Comment: Anything with a verb in it can be considered a clause for the purposes of that rule; clearly _were thrilled_ and _hearing_ have the same subject, so it behaves like a clause. In general, if you find that a grammar rule you have been taught looks like it's being broken, then you know that the rule was BS to start with. There's a lot of that around.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So, I am assuming that you agree that "after" is a subordinating conjunction joining the in question phrase/ clause to the independent clause.

Comment: It's also a preposition, and it can be considered either, depending on whether you consider the reduced subordinate clause as a noun phrase or a clause. Prepositions introduce noun phrases, and subordinate conjunctions introduce adverbial clauses, and this can be parsed either way. That's one reason why identifying the "part of speech" of a word seldom tells you anything useful.